# 403 Forbidden on the bucket

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, fine-uploader

I'm setting up fine-uploader for S3 as directed on the blog.  I've worked through a number of issues but now I am stuck.  Here is what I see on my web console in firefox...

javascript console output: http://tny.cz/ae7bc351 (pass is 2468).

client html code: http://tny.cz/93910c39

I'm using the java-servlet server implementation.  I'm not sure where to go from here since I believe I setup the bucket and the CORS config correctly.

If you would like direct access to my code, I'm willing to share that offline.

Thanks,
j

Comment: Please set the `debug` option to true, reproduce the issue, and paste the contents of the javascript console into your question, for starters.

Comment: The html client page states... "Invalid according to Policy: Policy Condition failed: ["eq", "$bucket", "fine"]

Comment: Here is the javascript console output after enabling debug...   http://tny.cz/ae7bc351  (pass is 2468)

Comment: Please paste the contents of the javascript console into your question by editing your question.

Comment: The response says that the bucket name encoded in the policy document does not match the actual bucket name that is being targeted.  This is likely due to an issue with your endpoint value.  Please post all of your client-side code in the question by editing your question.

Comment: I tested with a new bucket called "finetest1" and all is well.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Fine Uploader S3.  There is a regular expression that is used to determine the bucket name, given the S3 endpoint's URL.  The bucket name must be derived as it is one of the items that is signed before the request is sent.

Fine Uploader S3 uses a regular expression to determine the bucket name, but does not take underscores into account.  We will fix this at once and release a hotfix, which will be 3.9.1.  This issue will be tracked in our Github repo as issue [#1014](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/1014).

Comment: @Josh this issue has been address in Fine Uploader 3.9.1, which we just released.